# Unresponsive UIScrollView after dismiss modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

This issue is driving me crazy.

I have a `UIScrollView` with a content view that doubles its size. Scroll is enabled and `contentSize` is set. The content view has a pair of `UICollectionView` side by side so you can scroll the view between both of them (scroll paging is enabled too). Everything works ok until I select a cell. The app presents a modal with some info and, when I dismiss the `modalview`, the `scrollView` becomes unresponsive and doesn't scroll (but I still can select the `collectionView` cells!). It even change the contentOffset with animation to the proper "page" but doesn't scroll at all when dragging.

It sounds like the good old contenSize error but when I log the sizes in `viewDidAppear`, it has the right size.

FYI: I'm targeting iOS7 and I set the `scrollview` layout using storyboard with `AutoLayout`.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It seems that the constraints I set in storyboard weren't recreated when the modal was dismissed (I don't know why). Creating the layout by code did the trick.

Comment: @rmv3 - it seems like I am experiencing a similar problem. My ScrollView works fine until I push/pop a ViewController on its childNavigationController. After this it no drags to scroll! - any idea?